# Big O vs Small omega

Tags: complexity-theory

Why is ω(n) smaller than O(n)?

I know what is little omega (for example, `n = ω(log n)`), but I can't understand why ω(n) is smaller than O(n).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Algorithmic complexity has a mathematic definition.

If `f` and `g` are two functions, `f = O(g)` if you can find two constants `c` (> 0) and `n` such as `f(x) < c * g(x)` for every `x > n`.

For `Ω`, it is the opposite: you can find constants such as `f(x) > c * g(x)`.

`f = Θ(g)` if there are three constants `c`, `d` and `n` such as `c * g(x) < f(x) < d * g(x)` for every `x > n`.

Then, `O` means your function is dominated, `Θ` your function is equivalent to the other function, `Ω` your function has a lower limit.
So, when you are using `Θ`, your approximation is better for you are "wrapping" your function between two edges ; whereas `O` only set a maximum. Ditto for `Ω` (minimum).

To sum up:

- `O(n)`: in worst situations, your algorithm has a complexity of `n`
- `Ω(n)`: in best case, your algorithm has a complexity of `n`
- `Θ(n)`: in every situation, your algorithm has a complexity of `n`

To conclude, your assumption is wrong: it is `Θ`, not `Ω`. As you may know, `n > log(n)` when `n` has a huge value. Then, it is logic to say `n = Θ(log(n))`, according to previous definitions.

Comment: my question is about"Little Omega Notation"

Comment: Downvoted because this answer does not address the ω question.

Comment: @user3227, then you may want to consider accepting someone else's answer instead.

Answer (score 5):

Big Oh 'O' is an upper bound and little omega 'ω' is a **Tight** lower bound.

O(g(n)) = { f(n): there exist positive constants c and n0 such that 0 ≤ f(n) ≤ cg(n) for all n ≥ n0}

ω(g(n)) = { f(n): for all constants c > 0, there exists a constant n0 such that 0 ≤ cg(n) < f(n) for all n ≥ n0}. 
ALSO: infinity = lim f(n)/g(n)

n ∈ O(n) and  n ∉ ω(n). 
Alternatively:
n ∈ ω(log(n)) and n ∉ O(log(n))

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so first of all let me say that n ≠ Θ(log(n)). Big Theta means that for some positive constants c1, c2, and k, for all values of n greater than k, c1*log(n) ≤ n ≤ c2*log(n), which is not true. As n approaches infinity, it will always be larger than log(n), no matter log(n)'s coefficient.

jesse34212 was correct in saying that n = ω(log(n)). n = ω(log(n)) means that n ≠ Θ(log(n)) AND n = Ω(log(n)). In other words, little or small omega is a loose lower bound, whereas big omega can be loose or tight.

Big O notation signifies a loose or tight upper bound. For instance, 12n = O(n) (tight upper bound, because it's as precise as you can get), and 12n = O(n^2) (loose upper bound, because you could be more precise).

12n ≠ ω(n) because n is a tight bound on 12n, and ω only applies to loose bounds. That's why 12n = ω(log(n)), or even 12n = ω(1). I keep using 12n, but that value of the constant does not affect the equality.

Technically, O(n) is a set of all functions that grow asymptotically equal to or slower than n, and the belongs character is most appropriate, but most people use "= O(n)" (instead of "∈ O(n)")  as an informal way of writing it.

Answer (score 1):

ω(n) and O(n) are at the opposite side of the spectrum, as is illustrated below.

[image]

Formally,

[image]

For more details, see [CSc 345 — Analysis of Discrete Structures
(McCann)](http://www2.cs.arizona.edu/classes/cs345/summer14/files/bigO.pdf), which is the source of the graph above. It also contains a compact representation of the definitions, which makes them easy to remember:

[image]

Comment: I do not think that graph is correct. It certainly gives the wrong idea.  o(f) is stricter than O(f).  Anything that is O(f) time is also o(f) time.