# How to analyse time needed for an algorithm

Tags: array-algorithms

I'm new to programming and want to analyse algorithms before applying them. How to find time functions for the big oh, Omega and theta?

Comment: Make a prototype of the algorithm. Run small set of test data and then just calculate as you scale.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331479/determining-big-o-notation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27873104/big-o-vs-small-omega, and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%CE%98n-and-on

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between Θ(n) and O(n)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471199/what-is-the-difference-between-%ce%98n-and-on)